# which Theme that makes the Menu android with / without icon?

Tags: java, android, styles, themes, actionbarsherlock

I just realized when I used the normal (default) theme in android programming, the bottom menu shows good (text + icon).  [image]

But then,... when I use this code below:

```
<activity
           android:name="main.layout.Chat2Activity"
           android:label="Chat2Frame"
           android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock" >
</activity>
```

The icon dissapeared, and now the bottom menu only showing text, in vertical order. 
Which part of the Sherlock style theme that i can make the menu appeared as first time I mentioned (icon + text)?

Comment: try adding `android:showAsAction="always|withText"` to menu item xml. look into this [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html)

Comment: ouch! now the menu appeared as Tab-on its top side of the screen. Why is like that @SagarPilkhwal ? 
what's your code means anyway?

Comment: just go through the documentation, you can use `android:showAsAction=["ifRoom" | "never" | "withText" | "always" | "collapseActionView"]` in any combination as per your requirement, every theme has thier ways to show the menu items.